# Excel: data-driven marker style on plot

Tags: microsoft-excel

Is it possible to control the style of each data marker on a scatter plot based on a column? What I am specifically looking to do is call out a few markers by changing their style to an "x" rather than a point.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could change the data layout of the source data and move data points to different columns for the Y values. Then plot each Y value column as a different series and assign each series its own data markers. That way you can quickly move data points from one marker type to the other.

[image]

Comment: That's probably the best answer I'm going to get, but is there also a way to exclude the modified styles from the legend?

Comment: Of course. Click the legend to select it, then click a series in the legend to select that legend entry. Hit Delete to delete just that series from the legend.